# Change HTML5 button color when active

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color of my button when it is active or clicked. I have tried the following Html5 and css3 codes but have not been able to achieved my intentions.

HTML code:

```
  <p class="submit">
      <input type = "reset" />
      <input type = "submit" />
  </p>
```

CSS3 code:

```
   button.submit:active , button.reset:active {
     border: 2px solid #20911e;
     box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #356b0b inset; 
     background-color:blue; /* this is the line of interest */
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px 5px #356b0b inset ;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #356b0b inset;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #356b0b inset;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #356b0b inset;    
           }
```

I am using Chrome for the development, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS you use selectors in order to define the elements you want to configure. These selectors must match the targeted elements.

If you use the selector

```
button.submit:active
```

you're looking for an "button" element that has a class "submit" and is active. But there is no such element in your html code.

I have not the time to give an explanation of all possible selectors of CSS3. But there are good tutorials. This for example:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started

Change your CSS code to match input elements and add class to input elements.

```
 <p>
      <input type = "reset" class="reset"/>
      <input type = "submit" class="submit"/>
  </p>    

 input.submit:active , input.reset:active {
     border: 2px solid #20911e;
     box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #356b0b inset; 
     background-color:blue; /* this is the line of interest */
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px 5px #356b0b inset ;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #356b0b inset;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #356b0b inset;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #356b0b inset;    
           }
```

Comment: is a correct answer but can you explain the error to me

Answer (score 1):

Give your buttons a `class="submit"` and `class="reset"` respectively. No JavaScript needed. Also change your CSS3 code:

```
input.submit:active, input.reset:active {....}
```